# How to delete a table in Amazon Redshift only if the table exists

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to implement an ETL process in Amazon Redshift that needs to recreate certain tables automatically, and I need the script to drop those tables only when they are already present in the database.

Is there any table catalog where I can check for the presence of a table? Or a command similar to the `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS` in PSQL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:**

Now Redshift supports DROP TABLE with IF EXISTS clause.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DROP_TABLE.html

---

Since Redshift didn't support `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS`, we were handling it by getting existing table names.

To get table names on Redshift, I'm using `pg_table_def` table. For example, I run the following sql to get all table names excluding system tables.

```sql
SELECT
  schemaname, tablename
FROM
  pg_table_def
WHERE
  schemaname <> 'pg_catalog'
  AND schemaname <> 'information_schema'
  AND schemaname !~ '^pg_toast'
GROUP BY
  schemaname,tablename;
```

Here is a sample result.

```
 schemaname | tablename 
------------+-----------
 my_schema  | access_log
 my_schema  | error_log
 my_schema  | vmstats_log
 public     | users
 public     | groups
```

See the following link for the details.

- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_PG_TABLE_DEF.html

Comment: How can this be combined with an `IF`?  I'm seeing that `IF` doesn't seem to exist in RedShift either. Or would this have to happen in a custom script issuing multiple statements?

Comment: Now Redshift supports IF EXISTS clause as I updated my answer. My intension of the first post was handling it outside of SQL.

Answer (score 1):

How about instead of dropping the table you do an insert overwrite?

```
INSERT OVERWRITE INTO target 
SELECT s.* FROM staging s LEFT JOIN target t
ON s.primaryKey = t.primaryKey AND s.distKey = t.distKey
WHERE t.primaryKey IS NULL;
```

Otherwise try to explain to me why your doing what your doing and I will update with more help. This is a case of where by redshift design there is usually a reason why you can't do what you want, but there is a "redshift" way.

Comment: how i can do this in SELECT INTO statement?

Comment: remove "overwrite" from the query, would do the same thing as "select into"